# pyodbc.Error 'IM002' connecting to DB2

Tags: python, db2, pyodbc

I downloaded Python 2.7 (*python-2.7.1.amd64.msi*) and pyodbc, the python extension module for connecting to DB2 database (i.e. *pyodbc-2.1.8.win-amd64-py2.7.exe*).

I wrote sample script as shown below.

```
import csv 
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connectpyodbc.connect('DRIVER={DB2};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=DBT1;UID=scott;PWD=tiger;')  
curs = conn.cursor() 
curs.execute('select count(edokimp_id) from edokimp') 
print curs.fetchall()
```

The script throws following error

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

As I am a newbie to Python, I realized from the error that I need to download the IBM DB2 driver for pyodbc and hence searched extensively on Google but couldn't find any.

I would greatly appreciate if you could point me to the site where I can download the driver and later explain me how to configure/load the driver.

In case of Java

- the driver will be shipped in the form of *ojdbc.jar* which will be copied to the *lib* directory which will be on classpath
- make changes to configuration file
- reference the DataSource from Java Class

I am newbie to Python so I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know cooresponding steps with an example in Python.

Comment: I hope that's not your real password...

Comment: certainly not its standard database username/password i.e. scott/tiger :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [PyDB2 driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydb2/) on the project homepage.

If you run into compilation issues with the official Python, [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) is a good alternate distribution of Python on Windows.

Edit: If it asks you for DB2 headers, you need to get the [IBM Data Server Client for ODBC and CLI](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg27016878).

Comment: Thanks Leons. Wondering why can't i get it run using "pyodbc" unless i am missing something. I did looked into PyDB2 driver but as i am newbie to Python i dont know how to configure/load the driver. Do i need to make changes to configuration file like in JAVA and then call the DataSource from python script. An example will be greatly appreciated

Comment: PyODBC should work, but I think you need to define a data source. In Windows XP, you can do that under Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC) > System DSN.

Answer (score 0):

**It does work using pyodbc**. I think you have a wrong **connection string**. After some research and tests I solved with this code:

```
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=iSeries Access ODBC Driver;SYSTEM=10.0.0.1;UID=bubi;PWD=xyz;DBQ=DEFAULTSCHEMA;EXTCOLINFO=1')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from MYTABLE')
row = cur.fetchone()
if row:
    field1 = row[0] 
    field2 = row[1]
# etc...
```

As you see it **doesn't need a DSN** to be configured on your system.

Answer (score 0):

This connection string for pyodbc, work for me:

```
conexion_str = 'SYSTEM=%s;db2:DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DRIVER=%s;' % (self._SYSTEM, self._DSN, self._UID, self._PWD, self._DRIVER)
self._cnn = pyodbc.connect(conexion_str)
```