# iSeries (AS400) Output with ODBC connection

Tags: odbc, ibm-midrange

I am very new to AS400, and I am stuck. I have read documenation but cannot find what I need.
I have an odbc connection to an AS400 server. When I run this command I get an Outfile with everything I need:

```
CALL QSYS.QCMDEXC('DSPUSRPRF USRPRF(*ALL) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(CHHFLE/TEST3)', 0000000061.00000)
```

Instead of the results going to an outfile I need to receive the results of this command to my script that is connecting through odbc. If I change 'OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)' to 'OUTPUT(*)' I get no results when I try to 'fetchall()'.
Is there any way to get this information through the odbc connection to my script?

**EDIT:** I am on a linux server, in a python script using pyodbc to connect. I can run sql queries successfully using this connection, but I can't figure out how to get the results of a command to come through as some sort of record set.

Comment: So are you trying to get the results back as a RecordSet or ??  With what are you accessing this?  VBScript, .NET, or some other Windows Technology?  (Windows tech assumed because you're using odbc).

Comment: Although some people consider it mere semantics, the platform isn't an AS/400 any more.  The actual name really is unimportant -- unless you intend to search the web for help.  Searching with 'AS/400' will likely get you results from 10 years ago.  Unless you're working in Win98 that may not be helpful.  Try 'iSeries' or even the current name 'IBM i' as well.

Comment: @DavidStratton, I am on a linux server, running a python script using pyodbc.

Comment: OK.  I was halfway through writing my answer, but I think it still applies.  I think you still need to treat the file you just created as a database table.  You'll have to search for connection strings to the DB2 database and sample code if you're not sure how to access the DB2 from Python, but hopefully my answer will give you a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm interpreting what you're asking correctly.  it looks like you're accessing user profile data and dumping it to a file.  It looks like you then want to use the contents of that file in a script or something that's running on Windows.  If that's the case:

In general, when accessing data in a file from the Windows world, whether through ODBC and VBScript, or .NET, the AS/400 is treated like a database.  All files in libraries are exposed via the built-in DB2 database.  It's all automatic, and part of the Universal DB2 database.

So, after creating this file, you should have a file named TEST3 in library CHHFLE

You'd create a connection and execute the following SQL statement to read the contents:

```
Select * From CHHFLE.TEST3
```

This, of course, assumes that you have proper permissions to access this.  You should be able to test this using the iSeries Navigator tool, which includes the ability to run SQL Scripts against the database before doing it in your script.

*Added after reading comments above*

There's info at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452322/pyodbc-error-im002-connecting-to-db2) on connecting to the DB2 from Python.  I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`OUTPUT(*)` is not stdout, unfortunately.  That means you won't be able to redirect `OUTPUT(*)` to an ODBC connection.  Dumping to a DB2 table via `OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)` is a good plan.  Once that's done, use a standard cursor / fetch loop as though you were working with any other DB2 table.

Comment: My concern is that I will run a command that takes a while to run and populate the outfile, but after sending the server that command, my script then I will then immediately query the outfile before it's done being written.

Do I need to build in a delay or wait somehow check the outfile for completion?

Comment: I'd write a stored procedure that returns the result set you need with a single ODBC call.